# How do I debug a nopCommerce plugin while development?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, nopcommerce

I am looking for opportunities if there any way in which I can debug my nopCommerce plugin. I am working on a large sale product on nopCommerce therefore I am in such a critical situation to make a real time test or debug. Because I am quite unable to find out from where the exception is coming. Is there any available process or kit??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plugin debugging is the same as nopCommerce core debugging.

Please see admin area > system > log. It should have the entire stack trace. You can use it to the find where the exception is thrown from

Comment: But, how do I set a breakpoint above on a code? Because plugin is a compiled file. So how do I??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug an installed plugin, put a breakpoint in the method that calls the plugin.

For example, for *Shipping Rate Computation Methods*, you can put a breakpoint in **Nop.Services\Shipping\ShippingService.cs** in the **GetShippingOptions** method in this line:

```
var getShippingOptionResponse = srcm.GetShippingOptions(shippingOptionRequest);
```

Then just press F11 and you will be inside the plugin, debugging as usual.